# How to change the colour of a "cell" in a grid

Tags: java, processing

Apologies for a second post so soon but I am having trouble trying to change the color of a rectangle inside of a nested for loop.

When I click on a "cell" I want the stroke to change to (255,0,0) Inside my mouseClicked function I have already found a way thanks to this community to determine a number based on where I clicked. For example the top left cell is 0 and then it goes up by 1 and continues down the rows 12345678(new row)9 10 11 12 etc.

I have included my grid and my mouse clicked function.

```
final int COLUMNS = 8;
final int ROWS = 12;

int cellNumber;
int tileSize = 30;
int ellipseSize = 20;
int ellipseSpacing = 10;
int numMoves;
int selectedCell;
int targetX;
int targetY;
int randomTarget;
int gridX;
int gridY;
int score = 0;
int clickX;
int clickY;
int col;
int row;
boolean mouseoverColour = false;

void setup(){
  size (700,500);
  background(0);
  //drawTarget();
}

void draw(){
  drawColourgrid();
}

void drawColourgrid(){
   for(int i = 0; i < COLUMNS*tileSize; i+=tileSize){
     for(int j = 0; j < ROWS*tileSize; j+=tileSize){
       noFill();
       stroke(255);
       rect(i + 100,j + 60,tileSize,tileSize);
     }
   }
//fill(255);
//rect(100,60,240,360);
}

void mouseClicked(){
    if (mouseX >= 100 && mouseX <= 100+COLUMNS*tileSize && mouseY >= 60 && mouseY <= 60+ROWS*tileSize){
        mouseoverColour = true;
        col = (mouseX - 100) / tileSize;
        row = (mouseY - 60) / tileSize;
        cellNumber = row * COLUMNS + col;
        println(cellNumber);
    } else {
        cellNumber = -1;
        println(cellNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: `stroke(r, g, b`) will give you what you need

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz I should reclarify, I want to change the stroke of a cell inside the grid not all of them but a single one based on if I clicked on it or not.

Comment: Redraw that cell by doing `noFill();
       stroke(red, green, blue);
       rect(col + 100,row + 60,tileSize,tileSize);` Where `col` and `row` are the variables in `mouseClicked`

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz I'm having troubles finding where to put this code, if I put it in mouspressed it disappears once the mouse is released, if I put it in drawColourwell it draws but it doesnt draw on other cells when I try to click on them.

Comment: Add it right below the `println(cellNumber);` line of your `mouseClicked` function. I tested it in `https://valentin.dasdeck.com/processing/` and it worked.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz When I try and click on other "cells" lets say in row 5 and 2 across it draws ontop of the top left one but a little offset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202924/discussion-between-javier-silva-ortiz-and-nineofdiamonds-noah).

Answer (score 0):

I made 3 changes to your code to implement the "selection mechanic" you described:

1. initializing `cellNumber` to -1 (to avoid a false positive at start)
2. adding `background(0);` to the `draw()` loop to "reset" the grid so the selected cells stops looking like they have are being selected
3. drawing the red selected cell in `drawColourgrid()`

I modified the code the lest I could, so it stays your code. I recently helped one of your classmates, you might want to look into it.

Here's your modified code (with appropriate comments):

```
final int COLUMNS = 8;
final int ROWS = 12;

//initializing cellNumber to -1 to avoid a false positive at start
int cellNumber = -1;
int tileSize = 30;
int ellipseSize = 20;
int ellipseSpacing = 10;
int numMoves;
int selectedCell;
int targetX;
int targetY;
int randomTarget;
int gridX;
int gridY;
int score = 0;
int clickX;
int clickY;
int col;
int row;
boolean mouseoverColour = false;

void setup(){
  size (700,500);
  background(0);
  //drawTarget();
}

void draw(){
  //background to "erase" old selected cells when they are not selected
  background(0);
  drawColourgrid();
}

void drawColourgrid(){
  int selectedColumn = -1;
  int selectedRow = -1;

  if (cellNumber > -1) {
    selectedColumn = cellNumber % COLUMNS;    
    selectedRow = cellNumber / COLUMNS;
  }

   for(int i = 0; i < COLUMNS*tileSize; i+=tileSize){
     for(int j = 0; j < ROWS*tileSize; j+=tileSize){
       noFill();
       stroke(255);
       rect(i + 100,j + 60,tileSize,tileSize);
     }
   }   

   //this calculate which cell is selected and fill it with red
   if (selectedColumn > -1) {
     fill(255, 0, 0);
     stroke(255);
     rect((selectedColumn * tileSize) + 100, (selectedRow * tileSize) + 60,tileSize,tileSize);
   }
}

void mouseClicked(){
    if (mouseX >= 100 && mouseX <= 100+COLUMNS*tileSize && mouseY >= 60 && mouseY <= 60+ROWS*tileSize){
        mouseoverColour = true;
        col = (mouseX - 100) / tileSize;
        row = (mouseY - 60) / tileSize;
        cellNumber = row * COLUMNS + col;
        println(cellNumber);
    } else {
        cellNumber = -1;
        println(cellNumber);
    }
}
```

Have fun!